# What is missing in my javascript syntax for this to output the descending array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I thought I had a grasp on this. The task is to take this array:

```
var array = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
```

and output it in descending order. I have this so far:

```
function greatestToLeast(array) {
  array.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
}
```

So when I tried:

```
console.log(array);
```

the result was:

`(6) [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10]`

but the objective is for this to print out in descending order from greatest to lest.

But this is not outputting anything. What am I missing?

Comment: But this is not outputting anything? Are you logging it using `console.log`?

Comment: It's missing the `console.log` call that would actually output the array? Also you're not even calling the `greatestToLeast` function anywhere.

Comment: console.log(array)

Comment: @YoungKyunJin, logging array just gives me```Array(6)```.

Comment: These answers below are bad: no need to `return` anything because `sort` is sorting in-place.

Comment: @Ale please update your post with what you're doing: how did you get `Array(6)` by printing the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: Even though this answer has been marked as correct, There is something I noticed that might cause some problems:**

I just noticed that there's no point in adding the array parameter in the `greatestToLeast()` function as it is declared in the function scope, and I noticed that this may have been the issue all along.

---

You will need to add something like `console.log()` to output it to the console, or `return` your `array.sort()` statement.

For example, you could do:

```
function greatestToLeast (array) {
  return array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b - a;
  });
}
```

and call it with:

```
var array = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
console.log(greatestToLeast(array));
```

or, just `console.log()` it instead:

```
function greatestToLeast(array) {
  var sorted = array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b-a;
  });

  console.log(sorted);
}
```

(Note: the use of the variable `sorted` is not required, but I added it to make it easier to understand at a first glance.)

Also, you don't exactly have to return anything, as the function affects the array *itself*.

Therefore, after calling your function, array would have changed to it's decending order, and you could `console.log()` the original array:

```
var array = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
greatestToLeast(array);
console.log(array);
```

---

Overall, your syntax should be correct, just that you need to somehow *make* it return something rather than just making the changes and not ouput.

Hope this helps,

-Spy

Comment: Assassin, the first answer you gave me is what I got yesterday and I thought I understood the logic and syntax, but when I had to redo this today, I only remembered the custom function block and totally blanked out on how to print it out. Thank you.

Comment: I just edited the post a bit, explaining how passing in the array parameter may have been the culprit. You may want to take a look.

Comment: Assassin, don't second guess yourself, you do need to add the array like so: ```console.log(greatestToLeast(array));```. It's  the only way I get the right answer. With the first example you gave that is. Which is the one I had worked out yesterday. It is your second example, that does not work.

Answer (score -1):

You're probably not getting a result because your function `greatestToLeast` does not return anything (or perhaps you just forgot to log your result after calling the function, see second snippet). You can change your snippet to return the array if you want:

```
function greatestToLeast(array) {
    return array.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
}
```

But, since the `.sort` method mutates the array, you don't have to return it if you don't want to. Once you call the greatestToLeast function with it, it is already sorted even though the function returned no value:

```js
var array = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];

function greatestToLeast(array) {
  array.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
}

console.log("Not yet sorted:", array);
greatestToLeast(array)
console.log("Sorted:", array);
```